# TYPO3 alter table with Querybuilder

Tags: typo3, query-builder

How can you use the TYPO3 9 Querybuilder to execute an "ALTER TABLE" command?

```
ALTER TABLE foo
  DROP INDEX bar;
```

This class should be used to execute the query:

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;

...
$table = 'foo';
$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable($table);
```

Or is it necessary to instantiate another database object, which e.g. derives from the Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the Job:

```php
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;

// ...

GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)
    ->getConnectionForTable('foo')
    ->exec('ALTER TABLE foo DROP INDEX bar;');
```

The documentation warns about using queries outside repositories:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/6-Persistence/3-implement-individual-database-queries.html

Comment: This solution works. Could you also add the `use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;`?

Answer (score 0):

Give it try, this may be helpful to you. However, I have never tried to Alter table command before (Never required!!)

```
$connection = $this->objectManager->get(ConnectionPool::class)->getConnectionForTable($table);
$statement = $this->objectManager->get(
                   \Doctrine\DBAL\Statement::class
                   'ALTER TABLE foo DROP INDEX bar',
                   $connection
             );

$query = $this->createQuery();
$query->statement($statement);
```

Comment: at least in v10.x you should use GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class) instead of the ObjectManager

Comment: Thanks for correcting me @Naderio! I found reference [here](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/8.5/Feature-78116-ExtbaseSupportForDoctrinesNativeDBALStatementAndQueryBuilder.html#description)! As I said, I never used one ;)

Comment: ObjectManager::get has been marked as deprecated in TYPO3 10 LTS. 

https://forge.typo3.org/issues/90803 

And I do not have an Extbase class and therefore no `$this->objectManager` object.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be the usage of the Doctrine Schema Manager for such cases:

```php
use \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;

$connection = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getConnectionForTable('foo');
$connection->getSchemaManager()->dropIndex('bar', 'foo');
```

Answer (score 0):

For TYPO3v12 and up you can use:

```
$connection = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getConnectionForTable('foo');
$connection->executeStatement('ALTER TABLE DROP INDEX bar');
```

(Note: If you do that, you write database-specific queries, and you're locked to the database variant where this SQL is valid.)