# Alter Table with Querybuilder

Tags: typo3

is there a possibility to fire this line of sql via querybuilder or connectionpool?

```
'ALTER TABLE mytable AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;'
```

The solutions in [TYPO3 alter table with Querybuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63130803/typo3-alter-table-with-querybuilder) do not work anymore (TYPO3 12).

Comment: What does "do not work anymore" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This here should work:

```php
$connection = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)
  ->getConnectionForTable('mytable');
$connection->executeStatement('ALTER TABLE mytable AUTO_INCREMENT = 100');
```

(Note: If you do that, you write database-specific queries, and you're locked to the database variant where this SQL is valid.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But it is the same as in my link above: it does not work anymore. executeStatement() does not accept parameters.

Comment: It does, please check it out, I tried it :-) - executeStatement does not take parameters on the Querybuilder instance. This here is not the querybuilder instance, but a connection one. Those are on different layers.

Comment: Hi Garvin, you are right!! I always tried it with querybuilder ... stupid me :-) Thanks!

Comment: No worries! Thanks for getting back and telling me it works, happy it does!

Answer (score 0):

```php
$connection = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)
  ->getConnectionByName('Default');
$connection->executeStatement('ALTER TABLE mytable AUTO_INCREMENT = 100');
```

Try this (I have not tested it.). Make sure, that you use the correct name of connection defined in LocalConfiguration.php or AdditionalConfiguration.php.

Comment: Hi Dieter, thank you for your answer, you are right, it works. But Garvin posted the same answer already and explained why it did not work for me in the first try, so i marked his answer as correct. But of course your answer is correct too.